# Unable to send navigational goals on own robot

Tags: navigation, move-base, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am unable to send simple navigational goals to my own (physical) robot, with the following specs:

It runs diamondback on an internal computer, and ROS commands go directly to its motor controllers. I use a myrobot.launch file for this. In addition, I use an empty map server node, and a move base node very similar to the one in stage's navigation tutorial. The move base node has its static_map parameters both set to false. I can see a move_base/goal and move_base_simple/goal in rostopic list.

Now, if I  build simple_navigation_goals.cpp and send the goal of moving 1 m forward, the Action client waits forever for the server to come up. (This doesn't happen with, for example,when I run simulations on gazebo / stage, when I am promptly able to connect to the action server and see the result.) This may sound silly, but when I comment out the stageros node in move_base_amcl_10cm.launch in stage navigation tutorial, I get the same effect as above - the client waits forever for the server to come up. Note that without the stageros node, move_base_amcl.launch looks very much like my map-server + move_base combination.

I am unable to make sense of what's happening and would like to know how to connect with move_base action server.

Update after Eric's comment:

[map server :](http://pastebin.com/n01CwZig)  
 [move base launch file](http://pastebin.com/m9tFh2Da)

Our costmap files :
 [Base local planner](http://pastebin.com/4TNrDNwV)
 [Global costmap](http://pastebin.com/9d5tgZ9g) 
 [Local costmap](http://pastebin.com/a6eS6DdB) 
 [Costmap common params](http://pastebin.com/vjRPv1BQ)

Also, rostopic pub to move_base/goal or move_base_simple/goal hangs after latching the message.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10615/unable-to-send-navigational-goals-on-own-robot/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2011-07-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-07-17**:
Could you include your launch file and costmap configurations?

**Comment by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on 2011-07-17**:
No there are no errors in the terminals. move_base node (occasionally) keeps  perpetually waiting for the map that it never receives. The simple_navigation_goals client hangs waiting for the server.  I give all commands from the robot computer.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-07-17**:
Do you get any errors in the terminals? Are you running code on the robot computer and sending commands from a different computer over a network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that setting both static_map and rolling_window to false for a costmap is undefined behavior (this is how your global_costmap is configured). One of those should be set to true if you want the costmap to actually do anything.

Also, in your map_server launch, you seem to have forgotten a closing  tag.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) on 2011-07-20**:
The move_base node doesn't advertise its action server until it has completed setup. It sounds like, before, move_base was waiting for a map indefinitely, not allowing the node to complete its setup, and in-turn blocking the advertisement of its action server.

**Comment by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on 2011-07-17**:
Ah yes, I can see this. But still simple_nav_goals should at least contact server & send a goal.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-07-17**:
rostopic pub should appear to hang... it has to remain open for the message to actually be latched.

**Comment by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on 2011-07-17**:
I've changed rolling_window to false & static_map to true, Also, I've changed the robot_base_frame in the costmap.yaml files to be "map" to avoid any issues with TF. Still, the problem recurs. rostopic pub also hangs, also rostopic echo move_base_simple/goal shows the relevant goal.